# Web API Facebook Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-access-token, facebook-oauth

I am using the default code from ASP.NET Web api for facebook authentication. The facebook cookie is being passed to my ExternalLogin endpoint. However the claims about Email is not available.

User.Identity doesnt have a value for Email or a Claim for Email.

How can I get that additional information?

```
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        facebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "xx",
            AppSecret = "xxx"
           // Provider = new FacebookAuthProvider()
        };


        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
       // facebookAuthOptions.SignInAsAuthenticationType = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthOptions);
```

*`FacebookAuthenticatedContext.User`* doesnt only contains `id` and `name`

Using the FB SDK I can see my email..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there is no primary email for this user in facebook.
Maybe this answer can help you:

[Facebook MVC 5 ASP.NET Identity - Email is null for certain users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532442/facebook-mvc-5-asp-net-identity-email-is-null-for-certain-users)

Comment: Tried to add "context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Email", context.Email));" and I get a null exception..

Comment: When i use this sample API, I can see all my details .. https://supperslonic.com/SocialNetworks/OwinAuthentication

Answer (score 0):

If the email is being provided by Facebook, it is available as part of the external login information:

`var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
var loginInfo = await authenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();`

loginInfo is of type [ExternalLoginInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.owin.externallogininfo(v=vs.108).aspx) from which you can retrieve the email and other claims.